# How is the visual part of an application typically created?

Tags: java

I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question

As an amateur at programming who has been learning the basics of Java, I have started to wonder how the visual side of applications is created.

Basically I am wondering if there is a sort of equivalent to HTML/CSS for programs.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it. HTML/CSS/JS, or Swing, Qt, other choices. Choice depends on style of app, platforms supported, etc.

Comment: @joshp Say I wanted to make a program just like Notepad that works on Windows.  How would I do stuff like customize the toolbars or create even just a blank space for someone to type? I feel like the answer is something very basic but yet it still evades me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single answer because it really depends on the language, libraries, and approach you are taking.

At the most basic level, the OS and/or desktop system provides the necessary functions to build your GUI.  For example, on Windows, there's a `CreateWindow()` function that you can use to create a window (and buttons, and other controls).

Then there's cross platform libraries, such as Qt or wxWidgets.  They'll abstract the GUI elements so that their creation is the same across operating systems.  Either they'll draw them directly, or use an underlying widget library.

Another approach is to use a project such as Electron, which is a native executable that 'wraps' a web browser.  The application's interface is written in HTML & JavaScript.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, a check to you sir.